# Limiting GROUP BY based on COUNT() values in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, rdbms

I'm logging events into a mySQL database and would like to get the top 3 events for monitoring purposes.

My table `eventlog` looks like this:

```
+----+------------------+---------------------+
| id |    eventname     |      eventdate      |
+----+------------------+---------------------+
|  0 | machine1.started | 2016-09-04 19:22:23 |
|  1 | machine2.reboot  | 2016-09-04 20:23:11 |
|  2 | machine1.stopped | 2016-09-04 20:24:12 |
|  3 | machine1.started | 2016-09-04 20:25:12 |
|  4 | machine1.stopped | 2016-09-04 23:23:16 |
|  5 | machine0.started | 2016-09-04 23:24:00 |
|  6 | machine1.started | 2016-09-04 23:24:16 |
|  7 | machine3.started | 2016-09-04 23:25:00 |
|  8 | machine4.started | 2016-09-04 23:26:00 |
|  9 | cluster.alive    | 2016-09-04 23:30:00 |
| 10 | cluster.alive    | 2016-09-05 11:30:00 |
+----+------------------+---------------------+
```

The query should eventually return the following, holding

- the top 3 events that occurred most often (based on column `eventcount`s that is generated by mySQL's `COUNT()` function), grouped by their `eventname`
- only 2 rows where `eventcount` = 1, but only if 1 is within the top 3 `eventcounts` (since there are a lot of events that occur just
  once and therefore would overload my frontend)

Example of the desired result, based on the above table:

```
+------------+------------------+
| eventcount |    eventname     |
+------------+------------------+
|          3 | machine1.started |
|          2 | machine1.stopped |
|          2 | cluster.alive    |
|          1 | machine0.started |
|          1 | machine2.started |
+------------+------------------+
```

*Please note that I do not need just 3 returned rows but the rows with the 3 highest `eventcount`s.*

I did a lot of experimenting by messing around with the query string below, including multiple selects and questionable `CASE ... WHEN` conditions, but wasn't able to make it work the way I need.

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS 'eventcount', eventname
FROM eventlog
GROUP BY eventname
ORDER BY eventcount DESC;
```

What is the best approach to get the desired result in a performant way?

Comment: @RiggsFolly no, it won't. The desired result for the sample data has 5 rows

Comment: @Lamak Good point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is one way of doing it using variables
SQL Fiddle for it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b3458b/16

```
SELECT
  t2.eventcount
  ,t2.eventname
FROM
(
  SELECT
      t.eventname
      ,t.eventcount
      ,@Rank:=IF(@PrevCount=t.eventcount,@Rank,@Rank+1) Rank
      ,@CountRownum:=IF(@PrevCount=t.eventcount,@CountRowNum + 1,1) CountRowNum
      ,@PrevCount:= t.eventcount
    FROM
      (
        SELECT
          l.eventname
          ,COUNT(*) as eventcount
        FROM
          eventlog l
        GROUP BY
          l.eventname
        ORDER BY
          COUNT(*) DESC
      ) t
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT @Rank:=0, @CountRowNum:=0, @PrevCount:=-1) var
    ORDER BY
      t.eventcount DESC
) t2
WHERE
  t2.Rank < 4
  AND NOT (t2.eventcount = 1 AND t2.CountRowNum > 2)
```

Comment: For anybody wondering: @Gordon Linoff's and Matt's solution both work perfectly for my purpose. I accepted this answer since the query finishes a tick faster.

Answer (score 2):

These types of conditions in MySQL are painful.  One method uses variables.  Here is a method that doesn't:

```
SELECT el.eventcount, el.eventname
FROM (SELECT COUNT(el.id) AS eventcount, el.eventname
      FROM eventlog el
      GROUP BY el.eventname
     ) el JOIN
     (SELECT cnt
      FROM (SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(el.id) as cnt
            FROM eventlog el
            GROUP BY el.eventname
           ) el
      ORDER BY cnt DESC
      LIMIT 3
     ) ell
     ON ell.cnt = el.eventcount
ORDER BY el.eventcount DESC;
```

EDIT:

The solution using variables looks like this and includes the limit on 2 for a count of 1:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT e.*,
             (@rn1 := if(@c1 = eventcount, @rn1 + 1,
                         if(@c1 := eventcount, 1, 1)
                        )
             ) as rn
      FROM (SELECT e.*,
                   (@rn := if(@c = eventcount, @rn,
                              if(@c := eventcount, @rn + 1, @rn + 1)
                             )
                   ) as rank
            FROM (SELECT COUNT(el.id) AS eventcount, el.eventname
                  FROM eventlog el
                  GROUP BY el.eventname
                 ) e CROSS JOIN
                 (SELECT @c := 0, @rn := 0) params
            ORDER BY eventcount DESC
           ) e CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @c1 := 0, @rn1 := 0) params
      ORDER BY eventcount DESC
     ) e
WHERE rank <= 3 AND
      (eventcount > 1 OR rn <= 2);
```

The innermost count enumerates the counts.  The second enumerates within a count.  Actually, the two can probably be combined into a single subquery, but with care.

Comment: so this will correctly do the ranking, but in the a case that eventcount = 1 is in the top 3 results the OP only wants to return 2 of those records this will not limit that and will return all 4 in the test case above

Comment: @Matt yeah you're right, the ranking works great and it also seems to run highly efficiently but does not consider the limit for eventcount = 1 ...

Comment: DISTINCT COUNT GROUP BY ?? Eh?

Answer (score 0):

This should be able to be refactored a bit, but it returns the correct answer as of right now:

```
SELECT eventcount, eventname
FROM
(SELECT el.eventcount, el.eventname
FROM (SELECT COUNT(el.id) AS eventcount, el.eventname
      FROM eventlog el
      GROUP BY el.eventname
     ) el JOIN
     (SELECT counts
      FROM (SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(el.id) as counts
            FROM eventlog el
            GROUP BY el.eventname
           ) el
      ORDER BY counts DESC
      LIMIT 3
     ) el2
     ON el2.counts = el.eventcount
     WHERE el.eventcount != 1
UNION ALL
(SELECT el.eventcount, el.eventname
FROM (SELECT COUNT(el.id) AS eventcount, el.eventname
      FROM eventlog el
      GROUP BY el.eventname
     ) el JOIN
     (SELECT counts
      FROM (SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(el.id) as counts
            FROM eventlog el
            GROUP BY el.eventname
           ) el
      ORDER BY counts DESC
      LIMIT 3
     ) el2
     ON el2.counts = el.eventcount AND el2.counts = 1
     LIMIT 2)) tmp
ORDER BY tmp.eventcount DESC;
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/10f0d/92

Answer (score 0):

If you can use temporary tables..

Precalculate the eventcounts and store the result in a temporary table:

```
create temporary table tmp_eventcounts
  select eventname, count(1) as eventcount
  from eventlog
  group by eventname
  order by eventcount desc
;
```

Content of `tmp_eventcounts`:

```
|        eventname | eventcount |
|------------------|------------|
| machine1.started |          3 |
| machine1.stopped |          2 |
|    cluster.alive |          2 |
| machine3.started |          1 |
|  machine2.reboot |          1 |
| machine4.started |          1 |
| machine0.started |          1 |
```

Select the top 3 eventcounts and store them in another temporary table:

```
create temporary table tmp_top3counts
  select distinct eventcount
  from tmp_eventcounts
  order by eventcount desc
  limit 3
;
```

Content of `tmp_top3counts`:

```
| eventcount |
|------------|
|          3 |
|          2 |
|          1 |
```

Now select all eventnames with top 3 eventcounts but `eventcount` > 1.
Also select up to two eventnames with top 3 eventcounts but `eventcount` = 1.
Use UNION to combine the two results:

```
select eventcount, eventname
from tmp_top3counts
join tmp_eventcounts using(eventcount)
where eventcount > 1
union all (
  select eventcount, eventname
  from tmp_top3counts
  join tmp_eventcounts using(eventcount)
  where eventcount = 1
  limit 2
)
order by eventcount desc;
```

Result:

```
| eventcount |        eventname |
|------------|------------------|
|          3 | machine1.started |
|          2 | machine1.stopped |
|          2 |    cluster.alive |
|          1 |  machine2.reboot |
|          1 | machine3.started |
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b332df/1

If you can't use temporary tables you can replace their occurrences with their definitions an create a highly unreadable but working query:

```
select eventcount, eventname
from (
  select distinct eventcount
  from (
    select eventname, count(1) as eventcount
    from eventlog
    group by eventname
  ) tmp_eventcounts
  order by eventcount desc
  limit 3  
) tmp_top3counts
join (
  select eventname, count(1) as eventcount
  from eventlog
  group by eventname
) tmp_eventcounts using(eventcount)
where eventcount > 1
union all (
  select eventcount, eventname
  from (
    select distinct eventcount
    from (
      select eventname, count(1) as eventcount
      from eventlog
      group by eventname
    ) tmp_eventcounts
    order by eventcount desc
    limit 3
  ) tmp_top3counts
  join (
    select eventname, count(1) as eventcount
    from eventlog
    group by eventname
  ) tmp_eventcounts using(eventcount)
  where eventcount = 1
  limit 2
)
order by eventcount desc;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2eea6/4 ;-)

While this might look crazy, it can be easily created in PHP:

```
$tmp_eventcounts = "
    select eventname, count(1) as eventcount
    from eventlog
    group by eventname
";

$tmp_top3counts = "
    select distinct eventcount
    from ( {$tmp_eventcounts} ) tmp_eventcounts
    order by eventcount desc
    limit 3
";

$sql = "
    select eventcount, eventname
    from ( {$tmp_top3counts} )  tmp_top3counts
    join ( {$tmp_eventcounts} ) tmp_eventcounts using(eventcount)
    where eventcount > 1
    union all (
      select eventcount, eventname
      from ( {$tmp_top3counts} )  tmp_top3counts
      join ( {$tmp_eventcounts} ) tmp_eventcounts using(eventcount)
      where eventcount = 1
      limit 2
    )
    order by eventcount desc
";
```

Note: It looks like MySQL would need to execute the same subqueries again and again. But it should be able to cache the results and reuse them.

Answer (score -1):

You could try this out:

```
SELECT count(eventname), eventname FROM table
group by eventname
HAVING(count(eventname)) > 1
order by count(eventname) DESC
limit 3
```